# Selected value not shown using renderUI

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to develop a Shiny App with an `*Input()` function whose output depends on some results calculated in the server. You can find an example code below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sliderInput("mpg", "Mpg", min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg), 
                c(min(mtcars$mpg), max(mtcars$mpg)), ticks = FALSE, step = 1),
    uiOutput("cyl")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tableOutput("out")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  data_filtered_by_mpg <- reactive({
    filter(mtcars, mpg >= min(input$mpg),
           mpg <= max(input$mpg))
  })

  output$cyl <- renderUI({
    selectInput("cyl", "Cyl", choices = data_filtered_by_mpg()$cyl, 
                selected = data_filtered_by_mpg()$cyl[1])
  })

  output$out <- renderTable(data_filtered_by_mpg())

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The issue here is that the selected input of the select list is not the first element of the `data_filtered_by_mpg()$cyl` vector but `""`. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be due to the duplicates. Therefore try it with the unique values.

```
  output$cyl <- renderUI({
    cyl <- unique(data_filtered_by_mpg()$cyl)
    selectInput("cyl", "Cyl", choices = cyl, 
                selected = cyl[1])
  })
```

Comment: if it fulfills your requirements, i would appreciate an upvote :)